# Proper way to use Unicorn with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, unicorn

I notice that the default Gemfile that is generated by Rails 3.2.8 has unicorn commented out. What is the intended way to use it? If I uncomment out

```
gem 'unicorn'
```

then what is the intended way to invoke unicorn? The command

```
rails server unicorn
```

gives me a file not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle exec unicorn -c #{unicorn_conf} -E #{rails_env} -D`
`unicorn_conf` - path to unicorn config 
`rails_env` - rails enviroment

You must use unicorn with normal server like nginx